# JSon Map - React Native

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, dictionary, native

I have the following JSON in this format. I am using react native and am receiving this JSON from an API:

```
    {
        "2019-10-01": [
            {
                "respAgenda": "Cleber Romero",
                "cliente": "DAVI E FERNANDES LTDA",
                "dtIniti": "08:00",
                "dtInicioCompleta": "01/10/2019 08:00",
                "dtFimHora": "09:00",
                "idAgenda": "39250",
                "idChamadoAgenda": "44419",
                "tituloAgenda": "Visita solicitada pelo cliente - StreetC",
                "descricaoAgenda": "Visita solicitada pelo cliente - StreetCar.",
                "tipoAgenda": "",
                "idRespAgenda": "18",
                "dataAbertura": "2019-09-30 10:07:26",
                "dataInicio": "2019-10-01 08:00:00",
                "diaInicio": "1",
                "mesInicio": "10",
                "anoInicio": "2019",
                "dataFim": "2019-10-01 09:00:00",
                "diaFim": "1",
                "mesFim": "10",
                "anoFim": "2019",
                "corAgenda": "#DBDB70",
                "statusAgenda": "1"
            },
            {
                "respAgenda": "Hilver Mendes",
                "cliente": "COOPERATIVA PATENSE DE TRANSPORTES DE CARGAS E PASSAGEIROS LTDA",
                "dtIniti": "09:30",
                "dtInicioCompleta": "01/10/2019 09:30",
                "dtFimHora": "00:00",
                "idAgenda": "39275",
                "idChamadoAgenda": "44444",
                "tituloAgenda": "Implantação",
                "descricaoAgenda": "Implantação do sistema",
                "tipoAgenda": "",
                "idRespAgenda": "6",
                "dataAbertura": "2019-10-01 09:23:36",
                "dataInicio": "2019-10-01 09:30:00",
                "diaInicio": "1",
                "mesInicio": "10",
                "anoInicio": "2019",
                "dataFim": "2019-10-01 00:00:00",
                "diaFim": "1",
                "mesFim": "10",
                "anoFim": "2019",
                "corAgenda": "#bbbbbb",
                "statusAgenda": "1"
            },
                  (...)
        ]
    }
```

I need to map it so it looks like this:

```
      { 

       '2019-10-22': [{text: 'Cleber Romero, cliente x, etc etc...'}],
       '2019-10-23': [{text: 'Hilver Mendes, cliente x etc etc ...'}],
       '2019-10-24': [],
       '2019-10-25': [{text: 'Hilver Mendes, cliente x etc etc ...'},{text: 'Cleber Romero, cliente x, etc etc...'}]
                                        (...)
      }
```

Anyone know how to do this? I have tried several methods with map but nothing worked. My biggest problem is working with this data and grouping the text.

Comment: Please consider posting in English to receive more help. https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/07/23/non-english-question-policy/

Comment: Where are you getting the keys for the final map: '2019-10-22'? are those values in the array that you receive?

Comment: Hey Atlante, I receive this dates from the API.